# How do you exclude a top level EmbeddedEntity property index in Google Datastore with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, indexing, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, entity

I need to exclude a top level property from being indexed by Datastore (`payload` in the example below). The value of `payload` can really vary and the keys will easily have over 1500 bytes which Datastore limits in EmbeddedEntitites.

`payload` does not seem to be excluded from being indexed. Datastore throws the error that `content` is longer than 1500 bytes.

How do I exclude `payload` from being indexed? Thanks.

```
const transformedEvent = {
    id: "someString",
    name: "Some Name",
    payload: {
        content: "a very long string",
        foo: "bar"
    }
};

const entity = {
    key: datastore.key('Event'),
    excludeFromIndexes: ['payload'],
    data: transformedEvent
};

await datastore.save(entity);
```

Answer (score 4):

In your example, `content` and `foo` would also need to be added to the `excludeFromIndexes` array in order to be excluded. There is currently an [open issue regarding this on GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/issues/12#issuecomment-387543926).

Example:

```
const transformedEvent = {
    id: "someString",
    name: "Some Name",
    payload: {
        content: "a very long string",
        foo: "bar"
    }
};

const entity = {
    key: datastore.key('Event'),
    excludeFromIndexes: ['payload', 'payload.content', 'payload.foo'],
    data: transformedEvent
};
```

Comment: This is the working solution for anyone using NodeJS in 2023.